# Installation of WSE2012 Connector failed and stuck on lockscreen

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012

**Edit solution : My local account on Win 7 was the built-in Administrator Account. I renamed that account and I was trying to login with that alias. When I try to login with "Administrator" it works !**

---

I have set up a PC on my network with Windows Server Essentials 2012. I created several users and I wanted to connect my PCs with these users and my server.

I install with success the Windows Server Essentials 2012 Connector on a Win 8 Pro. I tried to install the Connector on a Win 7 Pro. Everything worked well and the PC reboot.

After the reboot, an error occured (I think a network problem, I don't remember exactly -_-). It canceled the installation of the connector.

Now, when my Win7 boot, I am stuck on the lockscreen where I am asked to enter login/pwd. If I enter the login/pwd of the new AD account, it failed (neither with the admin account nor the standard user).

I also tried to connect with the old local accounts but it failed to. May be the problem is beacause the local accounts don't have a pwd ?

The only solution I see now is formating the Win7 PC. But I'm still hoping someone here will find a solution ...

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english, I am not a native speaker.

Comment: If you've found a solution yourself, please post it as an answer. It will be easier to find for people facing the same problem.

Comment: I intented to, but as it was my 1st question, I had to wait 8h before answering myself. I have to wait tomorow to set my answer as "Accepted Answer" too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My local account on Win 7 was the built-in Administrator Account. I renamed that account and I was trying to login with that alias. When I try to login with "Administrator" it works !